# WebClient redirect to response page after POST of form

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webclient

I'm having some trouble trying to POST some form values to a page + redirect the user. For example:

- User clicks register button
- Some form values are populated
- WebClient POSTS these values and redirects to the external URL

I can achieve this without WebClient easily with an intermediate .aspx and a standard form with `onload="document.forms[0].submit()"` added to the body.

However, I would like to do this without an intermediate page. Is this possible using WebClient (or similar)?

I post my values like so: -

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection(8);
     nvc.Add("_charset_", "utf-8");
     nvc.Add("shop_id", "");
     nvc.Add("email", "");
     nvc.Add("amount", "");
     nvc.Add("curr", "");
     nvc.Add("paymentType", "");
     nvc.Add("kdnr", "");
     nvc.Add("ordernr", "");

     byte[] response = wc.UploadValues("https://www.trustedshops.com/shop/protection.php", nvc);
}
```

I can get the response from the byte array which is just the html of the page i post to, however, i want to actually send the user to the posted page so that they see the form prepoplated. Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up redirecting to an intermediate page and then doing the POST. The best you can do is post with the values. The request is made entirely outside of your browser in a separate thread from what I understand.

Comment: Gotta love serial downvoters..